# Null check operator used on a null value - state management with provider and getter error

Tags: flutter, dart, nullable, flutter-provider, state-management

I am building an Instagram clone with Flutter, and on the upload page, I'm trying to upload the image through a Provider and a Getter; code here:

```
final User user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;
```

the follow-up code is

```
user.photoUrl
```

Below is the Provider class Code:

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier{
  User? _user;
  final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();



  User get getUser => _user!;

  Future <void> refreshUser() async {

    User user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

I tried to upload a photo with the image picker dependency.

Below is the code:

```
pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
  final ImagePicker _imagePicker = ImagePicker();

  XFile? _file = await _imagePicker.pickImage(source: source);

  if (_file != null) {
    return await _file.readAsBytes();
  }
  print("No Image Selected");
}

showSnagBar(String content, BuildContext context) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Text(content),
    ),
  );
}
```

I am able to select the image alright. But in the process of uploading, I get the error of "Null check operator used on a null value". The debug console returns the following:

> The relevant error-causing widget was
>
> AddPostScreen
>
> global_variables.dart:13
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
>
> #0 UserProvider.getUser
>
> user_provider.dart:14 => this is the UserProvider class page dart file
>
> #1 _AddPostScreenState.build => this is the AddPostScreen() page dart file

Comment: Could you please add the code snippet around the line 13 of global_variables.dart, and line 14 of user_provider.dart. Please add the entire class if you can, and mark the line number where the error occurs.

Comment: global_variable 

"const homeScreenItems = [
  Center(
    child: Text("Home "),
  ),
  Center(
    child: Text("Search "),
  ),
  **AddPostScreen(),**  _this is line 13 of the global_variable.dart file_
  Center(
    child: Text("favourite"),
  ),
  Center(
    child: Text("profile"),
  ),
];"

Comment: "class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier{ 
User? _user; 
final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods(); 
**User get getUser => _user!;** this is line 14 of user_provider.dart file.
 Future <void> refreshUser() async { User user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails(); _user = user; notifyListeners(); } };" the above code is the entire class of the user_provider.dart

Comment: How do you guarantee that `getUser` isn't called before `refreshUser` completes?

Comment: I'm not sure about this but I'd be grateful if you have any solution. It's been over 48hrs and I'm stuck already. whachu thing @jamesdlin ?

Comment: You either need to avoid calling `getUser` until `refreshUser` has completed or you need to make `getUser` return a nullable type (and make all callers check whether it returns `null`).

Comment: @jamesdlin
can you please demonstrate that in a code for me?
i'd be much grateful...

Comment: Where are you using `refreshUser`?

Comment: I am using **refresher** here:

 at override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    addData();
  }

 ** addData() async {
    // ignore: no_leading_underscores_for_local_identifiers
    UserProvider _userProvider = Provider.of(context, listen: false);
    await _userProvider.refreshUser(); _here is the refresher used at_
  } **

Actually, it's in a dart file for configuring a web and a mobile responsive layout. @BouncyBits

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
User get getUser => _user!;
```

to:

```
User? get getUser => _user;
```

When the provider is initialized, _user is null, and depending on your programming logic, it could become null again. In these situations, if this getter (getUser) is called, this null exception will occur. That's why you should use the null-assertion operator **"!"** with caution.

Comment: please I am a beginner in flutter.  But when I use your answer, the itilized area of the the code below throws an error which says _a value of type 'user?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'User'_

**final User user = _Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;_**

Comment: Just curious. Do you know what the **"?"** in **"User?"** means? Please do not take this the wrong way. I just want to understand the level of explanation you would be comfortable with.

Comment: Theoretically, I think it's used to make a conditional statement. But in practice, I'd like to know more about it. @som-R91

Comment: Well, in a way you are correct. But in this case, **User?** means object is either a **User** object **OR** it is **null**. There are many nuances involved with flutter which should be easy enough to learn if you have a background in programming, which it seems you have.
I would sincerely recommend that you take a course on Flutter before embarking upon building an Instagram clone. 

"The Complete Flutter Development Bootcamp with Dart" by Angela Yu is a very good course in my opinion. https://www.udemy.com/course/flutter-bootcamp-with-dart/

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

1. Call the `refreshUser` in `initState()` or in the `init()` method of `Provider`,Or `FutureBuilder`, make sure you call it somewhere in the beginning as I dont see anywhere in the provided code.
2. Make the `User` nullable.

   ```
   final User? user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;

   user?.photoUrl ?? ''
   ```
3. Make the function `getUser()` nullable.

   ```
   User? get getUser => _user!;
   ```

Comment: I have been trying to do these but I'm still unable to solve the error.
when I try #2. I get an error which says. **The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.**

option 3 doesn't make any impact.

I don't how to do option 1 too.

Comment: I have updated the code for #2 , for 1st one you might have to make some research based in the above said lines

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
final User user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;
```

To:

```
final User? user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;
```

Make `User` nullable